# Change autocomplete key

Tags: bash, autocomplete

My tab key has stopped working, and as a result working on terminal has become painful. Is there a way I can reset my autocomplete key from tab to some other key? Also I do not have root access, so will it be possible for me to do it locally for my account?

Comment: I don't have access to a posix box at the second to give a good answer, but you might be able to figure out how to do it from [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/find-and-bind-key-sequences-in-bash/5683375) or [this](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html)

Answer (score 11):

Create a `~/.inputrc` file with the following:

```
C-SPACE: complete
```

and start bash again.  Control-space is now your additional auto-complete key

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd>, which also sends a tab character to the terminal.